# Grunt: documentation on how to run these before main program

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, typescript

I want to run my app like normal:

```
node app.js
```

but before that happens, I want to ensure that a particular grunt task is run first.

I am having trouble finding documentation on how to automatically run (and complete) a Grunt task before starting a node command.

To be more specific, I have TypeScript files that I want/need to compile before running my node.js application.

Is there a way to always run the compilation (with Grunt or another way) before running node? Perhaps I could do a simple synchronous call in my app.js to run Grunt, but that wouldn't be cool would it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use grunt to automatically compile typescript into a folder. Then you use nodemon in another window which is watching for changes in that folder.

Then when you change the typescript files, grunt runs (if you have set up grunt-watch) and after compile nodemon restarts the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any scenario with Grunt. Here, you can use both `grunt-ts` and `grunt-shell` tasks to run your program/server.

First one compiles/transpiles your code. Second one allows you to run any shell command, such as `node my_file.js`.